# Question about scipy.interpolate.interp1d

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to do linear scaling , for example:
There is a sequence A=[1,2,3,4],
So the length of A is 4, I want to do linear scaling to make a new sequence B
(Compare to A ,the length of B maybe 0.5times or 1.1times or 1.5,times and so on....)
For example: Suppose the scaling rate is 7/4 , the length of B is 4 * ( 7/4) = 7
Using linear scaling, the result of B sequence must be B=[1, 1.5 , 2 , 2.5, 3, 3.5 ,4]
How to use scipy.interpolate.interp1d to do that ? Or is there any other function could do that?
Input A to get output B (with any scaling rate )
Thank s a lot!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` can definitely do that for you. Have you read the documentation and tried something yourself? Is there something in particular that is not working as expected?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please be more specific regarding what you would like to achieve? What output B would you expect for a scaling rate of 2, for instance? [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy-interpolate-interp1d) may be indeed useful to you, but perhaps you may want to take a look at [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy-linspace).

Answer (score 0):

Due to linguistic competence, I am sorry that I cant describe what I want precisely.
Well I have finished this function:

```
enter code here
#vec[0]&vec[-1] will not change
#num is the numbers you want to add to vec
#num cant > vec
#It's Linear zoom function
#just change length=len(vec)-num can do Linear reduction! 

def linscale(vec,num): 
    ans=[ ]   
    length=len(vec)+num
    VL=len(vec)-1
    AL=length-1
    count=0
    for i in range(length-2):
     count+= VL/AL
     if int(count)/count==1:
      value=vec[int(count)] 
      ans.append(value)
     elif int(count)/count!=1:
      new=int(count)
      if new==0:
       value=(VL*vec[new+1]+(AL-VL)*vec[new])/AL 
       ans.append(value)
      elif new!=0:
       value=((count-new)*vec[new+1]+((new+1)-count)*vec[new])
       ans.append(value)

    ans.insert(0,vec[0])
    ans.insert(AL,vec[-1])
    return ans 
-------------------------------------------------
test=[1,2,3,4]
print(linscale(test,3)) 
print(linscale(test,2)) 

[1, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0]
[1, 1.6, 2.2, 2.8, 3.4, 4.0]
```